# Run local web application but restrict access to resources

Tags: c#, .net

I'll try to keep this coherent and to the point, been coding all day and a little fried right now. I know doing this is also entirely possible, I'm just not entirely how to do it directly.

The idea is I'm working on a program I'd like to make commercial and sell in the future. Currently it's been holding up to testing processes and everything looks good, but now that I'm starting the improve the program's GUI, I'm hitting limitations using Windows Forms (EI, tab control tops not being easily recolor-able, etc, etc), and had a thought... That I could make the GUI look infinitly better if I could import the program into a web page. Using a dot net project makes that relatively easy since I can copy the C# code over and after a bit of tweaking, it should be fairly straight forward to get everything running and then I just need to rewire everything to the web page GUI.

To handle launching the web page, I was contemplating making a program that creates a "harness" (Small graphic program that just runs a command prompt line to initialize the web service and provides a link to the web page being hosted on the local service. This approach works, but the big issue I'm hitting while probing this route is that the "Release" folder generated on the web application isn't fully self contained and in addition to this all resources are visible. (Hard to sell a product if the first person you sell it to can just distribute the source code around)

So ideally at this point, I'm looking to see if anyone can guide me in the right direct. I'm not sure how to go about creating a program that runs an app inside a local browser AND hides/otherwise makes all the code / resources (images, etc) unviewable/inaccessible to anything outside the program.

Sorry if this is a bit rambly, not entirely sure how to actually ask/find what I'm looking for. (There maybe a name for the thing I'm looking for and I've just never heard of it before.)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use WPF windows presentation foundation, you can make much more user friendly and intuitive interfaces in WPF comparing to windows form.

Developing and trying to sell a desktop program as a website is never recommended, the website is meant to be hosted on a server and let the clients access all of its functionalities within the browser. So I would suggest you to go and search for WPF.

You also mentioned that you are struggling to improve the windows form User interface design and are struggling to design attractive GUI. Well this is not true you can make amazing GUIs with windows form. take a look at this link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K9Ps66GoD-k this will greatly help you  to improve the existing windows form application design you already have developed.

Comment: Fair enough. I just know work has their development environment set up to run a web app through a harness so it's local to our machine, was simply contemplating how to go about doing that for this program. Going to stick with Windows Forms I suppose though and see if I can revamp the gui to something I like. Thanks.